# Where store reusable enum in grails

Tags: grails, enums

I want to store an enum describing 20 values for a field of a domain class. Where to put the `enum.groovy` so that I can use it from within many domain classes?

Answer (score 4):

I usually put them in src/groovy but I've also seen them put in the Domain themselves as transient properties.  I think either way is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

By Grails `Convention over Configuration` any supporting sources should be placed under `src/groovy` or `src/java`.